# Send an Alert using flow depends on the Opportunity Product/Opportunity lineitem

Tags: visual-workflow

Am trying to create a flow to send an alert if the Opportunity product/line items contains certain products.

But the flow isn't triggering an email although it is executing it.

Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to bear in mind when troubleshooting emails in flows

- Debugging a flow will not send an email even if all the values are set correctly (which makes sense). The only way I've found to test the email is to make the flow live, maybe with some filters so it only runs on a single test record
- The sender address can cause issues depending on how it's set. In our flows we have it set to the automation email but if you do this, you also need to set the senderType field to 'OrgWideEmailAddress' or the emails won't be delivered.

If you are testing with a live flow (not debug) and you have the appropriate sender email but the emails are still not being received, you can check the email logs under Setup > Environments > Logs > Email Log Files. You can request a log that will tell you if Salesforce sent the email.

This is NOT the same as confirming the email is being received though. If you can see the email is being sent via SF but people aren't receiving it, it's likely an issue on the mail server side, which your IT might need to investigate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).